# Mapbox not Working With Fragments and bottom navigation

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

**Mapbox not Working With Fragments and bottom navigation**
I get a blank page when i run the app , i am using bottom navigation bar and inside the fragment i run the mapbox code , i am trying to add Mapbox view inside the fragment .. i tried to implement the map box inside onViewCreated() but it doesn't work either.
.
.
.
.

```
public class TrackingFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private MapboxMap map;
    private MapView mapView;

    public TrackingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(), getString(R.string.access_token));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tracking,container,false);
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        map = mapboxMap;
        map.setStyle(Style.DARK);
    }

    private void enableLocation() {
        // the permission is granted.
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(getContext())) {
            //tracking();
        } else {
            // the permissions is not granted.
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            //here we request for location from user
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(getActivity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocation();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything seems okay in your code. I tried your code and it display's the map. Please, check your mapbox_access_token. If still exist a problem, let me know.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me after adding ```Mapbox.getInstance(this,getString(R.string.access_token));
``` in the onCreate() of MainActivity

Comment: can you accept this as an answer if I change the comment into the answer? it would be helpful to me.